# Exclude tabs based on Tac Lite permissions

Tags: 6, hooks, routes

I'm currently using Tac Lite to grant editing permissions to individuals throughout the site. If a user has access to edit a particular node the edit tab appears, if they don't they won't see the tab. However, I also have both the Workflow and Revisions modules enabled and both the Workflow and Revisions tabs show up on every page, meaning that particular users are able to move content to other states (but can't edit it.)
This is due to having 3 roles - author, editor, and publisher. These 3 roles can move content through certain parts of the workflow.
Tac Lite controls who can view based off of department. For example Finance people can edit Finance content. So 2 roles together would be Finance + Author or Finance + Editor.

I am looking for the variable to use to check if an individual has access to edit a particular node and if not hide the workflow and revisions tabs from them.

So far the module looks like this

```
function tabremoval_menu_alter(&$items) {
//these are the menu items to hide 
$item['node/%node/workflow']['access callback'] = 'tabremoval_override_access';
$item['node/%node/revisions']['access callback'] = 'tabremoval_override_access';

}
function tabremoval_override_access($node) {
if (node_access('update', $node, $user)) {
return TRUE;
}
}
```

But my if statement logic seems to be off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to get the current user and node you pass to node_access first somehow?